# insert variable text after another variable text on a specific line

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to insert variable text after another variable text on a specific line. Below is my attempt so far, as far as I can tell, if I can escape the quotations in `awk` so that the variable can be seen and still applied, then it should work, but I have no idea how to do this :

```
#!/bin/sh

VAR=$(head -n1 ~/Scripts/tmp/file.txt)
VAR1=$(head -n1 ~/Scripts/tmp/file1.txt)

awk '/$VAR/ { print; print "$VAR1"; next }1' ~/Scripts/tmp/file.txt
```

Comment: Don't fall into the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) trap: what is your actual input and desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass strings to an awk script, pass them through environment variables.

```
export VAR VAR1
awk '
    1
    $0 == ENVIRON["VAR"] {print ENVIRON["VAR1"]}
' ~/Scripts/tmp/file.txt
```

I reorganized your script to make the logic simpler. I also replaced the regexp matching by a string comparison: with regexp matching, `$VAR` would be treated as a regular expression, it wouldn't perform a string comparison. And `/$VAR/` wouldn't even use the value of `VAR` (that's Perl syntax, not awk), you'd need `match($0, VAR)` for that.

A note on some other solutions that don't really work (they work only if the variables don't contain any special character, which character is special depends on the method):

- `awk -v awkvar="$VAR" '$0 == awkvar …'` expands backslashes in the line content.
- `awk "/$VAR/" …` makes the shell expand the value of `VAR` as an awk snippet. For example, if `file.txt` contains `^/ {system("touch ~/naughty")} /` then the command `touch ~/naughty` is executed.

An alternative approach is to make awk read all the files.

```
awk '
    BEGIN { VAR1 = getline <"~/Scripts/tmp/file1.txt"; }
    NR == 1 {VAR = $0}
    1
    $0 == ENVIRON["VAR"] {print ENVIRON["VAR1"]}
' ~/Scripts/tmp/file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the break down as well, as i'm still new and learning at the moment. Your correction worked perfectly, but i realised i need to add a tab between variable and variable 1, so have adapted it to: export VAR VAR1
awk '
    1
    $0 == ENVIRON["VAR"] {print ENVIRON["VAR1"]}
' ORS=' ' ~/Scripts/tmp/file.txt > ~/Scripts/tmp/file2.txt

Answer (score 1):

One possible AWK solution:

```
   awk '/'$VAR'/ { print; print "'$VAR1'"; next }1'
```

break the ' quotations around all your external variable.

Another possible solution like the other post suggest with passing variables is to pass VAR1 in as an awk variable but I think you still need to do the single quote block escape for the pattern using VAR:

```
 awk -v var=$VAR1 '/'$VAR'/ { print; print var; next }1'
```

You could try sed instead :) it is specifically designed for this sort of substitution.

```
 sed "s/$VAR.*/\0\n$VAR1/" ~/Scripts/tmp/file.txt
```

if you can have multiple instances of VAR on a single line then add g at the end of the sed command (global) so that it will not stop at the first match it finds:

```
 sed "s/$VAR.*/\0 $VAR1/g" ~/Scripts/tmp/file.txt
```

IMPORTANT!: make sure the '/' character does not appear in the VAR or VAR1 variable, if they can you need to escape them for awk or sed, alternatively with sed you can change the delimiter for the command to something else like ';' for example:

```
 sed "s;$VAR.*;\0\n$VAR1;" ~/Scripts/tmp/file.txt
```

Explanation of the sed command:
        We use the double quote" instead of single quote around the sed command so that variables like VAR and VAR1 will be replaced by their values. This happens before the command is executed by sed which is why if the / can be present in the variable content that you need to address it (this is true for awk as well)
        The 's' indicates that you writing a substitution command of the form:
s/<pattern>/<replacement pattern>/ 
        The '/' immediately after the s is the delimiter that will be used to separate the sections of the command. so if you put ; you must use ; everywhere like shown above.
        The pattern to match will be the content of the $VAR variable.
        The substitution pattern is \0 which means print what was match by the pattern a new line '\n' and the content of VAR2.

OOPS did not see the part about line bellow.. fixed patterns.

Comment: Note that all of your proposals fail if the value of `VAR` contain certain characters. You've discussed some of the problems but not all. In addition to `/`, all characters that are special in regexps will fail (the value of `VAR` is interpreted as a regexp, or in some of the commands the result of the split+glob operator on the value because [you forgot the double quotes around shell variable substitutions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)).

Comment: Yes you are correct :).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `awk`, you have to pass the `bash` variable to `awk` with the `-v` option :

```
awk -v v=$VAR -v v1=$VAR1 '/v/ { print; print v1; next }1' ~/Scripts/tmp/file.txt
```

But check Rob's answer for more correct and detailed solution.

Comment: Did you test this before posting? Your advice about passing variables with `-v` is good, but the usages `/$VAR/` and `print "$var"` will fail I think

Comment: Yep there are two variables, and you do not wnat the " or $ in front of var :)

Comment: ... and AFAIK you can't use variables inside a `/.../` regex match: use `$0 ~ var` instead

Comment: You can break the '' block around your variables :)

Comment: yeah you are right. I haven't tested. corrected post

Comment: @Rob great stuff, i didn't know that you can also use bash variables with double and simple quote

Comment: You cannot :) you have to break the single quotes first.. if you look closely in my post you will see the " is before the break in the single quote block so that the awk script sees the " in its script, you then break the single quote block, use the terminal variable which will be textually replaced reopen the single quotes close the double quotes and finish the awk script :) Narly but it works :)

Comment: `/v/` looks for lines containing the letter `v`, it has nothing to do with the variable `v`. You're missing [double quotes around variable substitutions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). `awk -v v="$VAR"` fails when `$VAR` contains backslashes, e.g. `awk -v v="\\n"` sets `v` to a newline.